# Flex 4 Spark Transitions - Possible to include from outside the component mxml?

Tags: flex4, mxml, transition

**I'm wondering:** *Is it possible to build the transitions mxml outside the mxml component they are meant to be used in?*

For example, like how the Script tag can have a `source = property`.

I'd like to be able to keep the component mxml nice and tidy but also keep the transitions declared via mxml.